# RemoveTimestamp Rx (removed but not forgotten)

Tags: .net, system.reactive

So the hugely out of date Hands-on-Labs (HoL) uses the `RemoveTimestamp` method which was removed in a later release. I'm not entirely sure what its behavior was supposed to be. From the HoL this extension method was provided:

```
public static IObservable<T> LogTimestampedValues<T>(this IObservable<T> source, 
    Action<Timestamped<T>> onNext)
{
    return source.Timestamp().Do(onNext).RemoveTimestamp();
}
```

Is there any replacement, or does anyone know the new operation/expected behavior for this method? `Timestamp` still exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just define the extension method yourself, removing the [`Timestamped` wrapper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228977.aspx) manually by calling [`Select` extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reactive.linq.observable.select.aspx) and returning the [`Value` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh211673.aspx) from the `Timestamped` instance:

```
public static IObservable<T> LogTimestampedValues<T>(this IObservable<T> source, 
    Action<Timestamped<T>> onNext)
{
    // Validate parameters.
    if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
    if (onNext == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("onNext");

    // Timestamp, call action, then unwrap.
    return source.Timestamp().Do(onNext).Select(t => t.Value);
}
```

However, to be *truly* effective, you really want to define an overload that takes an [`IScheduler` implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reactive.concurrency.ischeduler%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) and calls the [`Timestamp` extension method overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh229003%28v=vs.103%29.aspx):

```
public static IObservable<T> LogTimestampedValues<T>(this IObservable<T> source, 
    Action<Timestamped<T>> onNext, IScheduler scheduler)
{
    // Validate parameters.
    if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
    if (onNext == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("onNext");
    if (scheduler == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("scheduler");

    // Timestamp, call action, then unwrap.
    return source.Timestamp(scheduler).Do(onNext).Select(t => t.Value);
}
```

You want to do this, as you might have a specific scheduler that you want the logging to use.

If you *aren't* passing an `IScheduler` implementation in, then the initial extension method is nothing more than a thin wrapper over the [`Do` extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh229804%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) and doesn't provide much value.

Comment: Perfect, I sort of assumed it would be something like that, I was trying to "select" the contents of the ITimeStampedObservable (or what ever it is called) but without using the actual word "Select". :)

Answer (score 2):

Tada!

```
public static IObservable<T> RemoveTimestamp<T>(this IObservable<Timestamped<T>> This)
{
    return This.Select(x => x.Value);
}
```